# Java - Printing an empty square using nested loops

Tags: java

I am working on printing a quasi-empty square that looks like the example below (10 asterisks across and 10 down for the 2 columns):

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

My code cannot dynamically generate squares as specified by the user's input for the number of rows and columns (it is working for 10 rows and 10 columns, but as soon as I change the number to 20, the number of the asterisks does not change. The following is my code:

```
String STAR = "*";
String star1 = "**********";
int MAX = 10;
for (int row = 0; row <= MAX; row += 1 ) {
    for (int col = 0; col <= MAX ; col += 10) {
        if (row == 0 && col == 0)
            System.out.println(star1);
        if (row >= 1 && row <= 4)
            System.out.println(STAR + "        " + STAR);
        if (row == 10 && col == 10)
            System.out.println(star1);
    }
}
```

Any help/advice is welcomed regarding the dynamism of the code.

Comment: Your code does not show where you capture the user input.

Comment: I suggest you start by trying to debug your program with your debugger. Is there any reason your columns increment by 10?

Comment: You have hard coded so many values here that it will not work if the user supplies anything other than ten. You will need to change your definition of star1 based on the user input as well as a host of other things! And what is the row >=1 && row <=1? It seems wrong and won't work for ten also.

Comment: Also, add the homework tag if it is homework please.

Comment: Here is a program in C to print empty square [C program to print empty square](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/07/c-program-to-print-hollow-square-star-pattern.html). You can translate it in Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
String star = "*";
String space = " ";

int MAX = xxx;

for (int row = 0; row < MAX; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < MAX; col++) {
    if (row == 0 || row == MAX - 1) {
      System.out.println(star);
    } else if (col == 0 || col == MAX - 1) {
      System.out.println(star);
    } else {
      System.out.println(space);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your nested loop:

```
for (int col = 0; col <= MAX ; col += 10) {
```

So when `col` is 10, you're really only just iterating once... you might as well not have the nested loop at all.

Additionally, both `star1` and the string literal with spaces have a fixed number of characters in them, clearly related to the number of columns.

I'm assuming this is homework, so I won't give any more hints than that to start with, but hopefully that'll get you thinking along the right lines...

Answer (score 0):

You should change the 3 occurrences of `10` in your two `for` loops by the `MAX` variable, so when the user define another size, your `for` loop will take his input instead of the `10` value.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at your last if statement there where it says `if (row == 10 && col == 10)` and think about it for a second. Once you have hit 10 rows and 10 columns, you are just going to print your final horizontal line of `star1` regardless of what `MAX` is set too.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above, the nested for loop is unnecessary and can be inefficient if you plan to create larger rectangles in the future (not saying you're going to have to but try to stay away from nested for loops if you can). Instead, just print star1 before your loop begins and after it exits. The body of the loop should be simple enough. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String tenStars="**********";
        String oneStar="*";
        int count=0;

        System.out.println(tenStars);
        count++;
        while(count<=8)
        {
            System.out.println(oneStar+"     "+oneStar);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print(tenStars);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    public static void hallowSquare(int side)
{
    int rowPos, size = side;

    while (side > 0)
    {

        rowPos = size;

        while (rowPos > 0)
        {

            if (size == side || side == 1 || rowPos == 1 || rowPos == size)
                System.out.print("*");

            else
                System.out.print(" ");
            rowPos--;
        }
        System.out.println();
        side--;

    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, a more versatile one. It lets you create a hollow rectangle of height "h" and width "w"

```
     private static void hallowSquare(int h, int w)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=h; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=w; j++)
        {
            if (j==1|| j==w || i==1 || i==h )
            System.out.print("X");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this with one user input ... this is working

```
public static void drawSquare(int size)
{
       for(int i=1; i<size ;i++)
       System.out.print("*");
       System.out.println("");
       for(int i=0; i<50 ;i++)
       {
              System.out.print("*");
              for(int j =0; j<size-3; j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");
              System.out.println("*");
       }

       for(int i=1; i<size ;i++)
              System.out.print("*");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    drawSquare(50);
}
```

you should just create a class in put this inside your class and run it ... I hope this will help you ....

Answer (score 0):

```
class Star8
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
            {
                if(i==2||i==3||i==4 )
                {
                    System.out.print("*    *");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }    
            System.out.println();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please take care to ensure your code is nicely formatted with the correct indenting, no unnecessary white space etc. I've made some changes to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, simplify your thinking mate. Think about the axis x and y and work by that logic. Make a nested loop on ur for loop that passes lines, in each case loop the number of 
the size of square and print a space, after the nested loop print the "*".

```
> for (int b=0;b<ans*2-3;b++)
```

This nested loop has the max value of b because:

remember that while ur printing, each "*" is distanced from the other by a space, and remember u are only counting space between the first and last column. Meaning all space
between x=0 and x=squaresize, therefore max b should be the space between these 2 coords.
which are: squaresize * 2 /*the 2 is for the added spaces*/ -3/* -3 because u leave out the first coord(x=0),last coord(x=squaresize), AND 1 space added from the former loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AsteriksSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int ans;
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the side of the square: ");
        ans=input.nextInt();
        String ast="*";
        if (ans>0 && ans<21){

            for(int i=0;i<=ans-1;i++){
                System.out.print("* ");


        }
            System.out.println("");
            for(int i=1;i<=ans-2;i++){
                System.out.print("*");
                for (int b=0;b<ans*2-3;b++){
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
                System.out.println("*");


        }
            for(int i=1;i<=ans;i++){
                System.out.print("* ");


        }

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class  square1
  {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
       String star = "*";
       String space = " ";
       int MAX = 5;
      for (int row = 0; row < MAX; row++) 
        {
          for (int col = 0; col < MAX; col++) 
            {
             if (row == 0 || row == MAX - 1) 
              {
                System.out.print(star);
              } else if (col == 0 || col == MAX - 1)
              {
                System.out.print(star);
              } else {
               System.out.print(space);
              }
          }
        System.out.println();
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for answering. This question has 11 other answers, so as well as posting code you might want to add some text explaining why your solution is a good one and better than some of the others. You can do this by clicking the edit button below your answer and adding the text. This might get you some votes of support or admiration for your effort.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick.

```
package javaPackage;

public class Square {   

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<=10;j++)
            {
                if(i==0||i==10){
                    System.out.print("x");
                }
                else if(j==0||j==10){
                    System.out.print("x");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If the interpreter sees that you're on the first and last line(i=0 and i=10), it will fill the row with x. Else, it will only print a x at the beginning and the end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below two methods.

1) One with minimal line of code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 9) {
                System.out.println("* * * *");
            } else {
                System.out.println("*     *");
            }
        }
```

OR

2) With the help of two for loops

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 9) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        if (j == 0 || j == 9) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Thanks,
Stuti

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Star
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the row : ");
        int row=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the column : ");
        int column=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=column;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for(int i=row-2;i>=1;i--)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("*");
            for(int k=1;k<=column-2;k++)
            {
                if(i<1)
            {
                break;
            }
                System.out.print(" ");

            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=1;i<=column;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What is it, and how does it answer the user's question? Edit that into the answer.

Comment: @ Ares In above code user can give the size of row and column to print *.

Answer (score -1):

I am hopeful the code below can help, used very simple coding and have the required result.

```
a=eval(input('Provide the height of the box: '))
b=eval(input('Provide the width of the box: '))
d=a-2
r=b-2

if a >= 1:
   print('*'*b)
if a > 1:
   for i in range(d):
       print('*',end='')
       for i in range(r):
           print(' ',end='')
       print('*')
   print('*'*b,end='')
```

The result is:
[image: The following result is for the height: 6 and width:15]